# How to combine Poisson distribution with given chance p?

Tags: probability

There's an exercise I have to solve that says that the amount of eggs that a chicken lays is Poission distributed with parameter lambda. The chance that an egg breaks before it hatches is $p$. The question is: What is the chance that all eggs break?

I have tried several things but can't figure it out. The solution is also given and it's $e^{(-\lambda*(1 - p))}$. Can somebody explain how to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0):

So let $N$ be the $RV$ for the number of eggs laid
$$f_{N}(n) = \frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda} $$
Let $K$ be the number of eggs that break
$$f_{K|N}(k|n) = { n\choose k}p^{k}(1-p)^{k} $$
Probability that all of $n$ eggs break 
$$f_{K|N}(n|n) = \mathbb{P}(N = n| K = n)$$
$$ =\frac{\mathbb{P}(K=n|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)}{\mathbb{P}(K=n)} $$
$$ =\frac{\mathbb{P}(K=n|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)}{\sum_{m}\mathbb{P}(K=m|N=m)\mathbb{P}(N=m)} $$
$$\frac{p^{n}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}}{\sum_{m}{m\choose m}p^{m}.\frac{\lambda ^{m}e^{-\lambda}}{m!} }$$
$$\frac{p^{n}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}}{\sum_{m}p^{m}.\frac{\lambda ^{m}e^{-\lambda}}{m!} }$$

I am slightly lost after this too, would be interested in what other people answers are.

PS: I see that the OP should show what he/she has tried, but downvoting an interesting question for this, is kinda unfair to fellow stack users.